# Calculate using dplyr, percentage of NA'S in each column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with some columns  with missing values. Is there a way (using dplyr) to efficiently calculate the percentage of each column that is missing i.e. NA. Sought of like a colSum equivalent. So I dont have to calculate each column percentage missing individually ?

Comment: You should provide a data object for testing.

Comment: `colMeans(is.na(x))` (base R rather than `dplyr`) might work.

Comment: Your question is about `dplyr`. `Calculate using dplyr`.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, I created a test data for you:

```
a<- c(1,NA,NA,4)
b<- c(NA,2,3,4)
x<- data.frame(a,b)
x
#    a  b
# 1  1 NA
# 2 NA  2
# 3 NA  3
# 4  4  4
```

Then you can use `colMeans(is.na(x))` :

```
colMeans(is.na(x))
#    a    b 
# 0.50 0.25
```

Comment: Thanks to Ben Bolker comment.

Comment: Thank you, will add data next time

Answer (score 17):

We can use `summarise_each`

```
 library(dplyr)
 x %>% 
   summarise_each(funs(100*mean(is.na(.))))
```

Answer (score 8):

Loving the concision of `purrr::map` for this type of thing:

`x %>% map(~ mean(is.na(.)))`

Comment: x %>% map(~ mean(is.na(.))) %>% keep(~ 1 %in% .) %>% names()

This keeps only the columns who are all na.