# Calculate column NA's based on a grouping variable with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I couldn't find any similar question although I doubt that this has not been posted before. My question is related to 
[Calculate using dplyr, percentage of NA'S in each column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512837/calculate-using-dplyr-percentage-of-nas-in-each-column?answertab=votes#tab-top).

---

In a dataset whith are multiple observations per subject, it is useful to not only calculate the total number of missing data entries (i.e. total NA's per column) but also *how many* subjects have missing data of some sort.

For instance, in dataset `db` (see below) `item_1` is missing for 2 subjects  and `item_2` is missing for 1 subject.

> **Edit 1:** What I am interested in is how many subjects have (any) missing value per item. Even if in `item_2` there are two missing observations for subject number 1, this should be counted as 1 since it is still the same subject.

```r
library("dplyr")

db <- data.frame(
  subject = c(1, 1, 1, 2),
  item_1 = c(NA, 2, 3, NA),
  item_2 = c(1, NA, NA, 4)
)
db
#>   subject item_1 item_2
#> 1       1     NA      1
#> 2       1      2     NA
#> 3       1      3     NA
#> 4       2     NA      4
```

My approach so far was to `cbind` all single calculations into one new `data.frame` but this quickly gets messy (with more columns) and is surely not well coded.

> **Edit 1**: However, this shows the desired values, as `item_1` is missing for two subjects (1 *and* 2) and item_2 is only missing for 1 subject (subject 2).

```r
cbind(
  db %>%
    filter(is.na(item_1)) %>%
    summarise(na_item_1 = n_distinct(subject)),
  db %>%
    filter(is.na(item_2)) %>%
    summarise(na_item_2 = n_distinct(subject))
)
#>   na_item_1 na_item_2
#> 1         2         1
```

**Question**: is there an approach in `dplyr` to calculate this?

Ideally, I would also like to add the proportion of missings somewhere (like in the example below):

```r
data.frame(
  type = c("n", "proportion"),
  na_item_1 = c(2, 1.0),
  na_item_2 = c(1, 0.5)
)
#>         type na_item_1 na_item_2
#> 1          n       2.0       1.0
#> 2 proportion       1.0       0.5
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why does item_2 have 1 missing value?

Comment: It is about the subject and not the values. What I mean is that item_2 has missing values for 1 subject (subject number 2). I will try to make this clearer in the post.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @RonakShah. This is wrong. It should be 1.0 as 2 out of 2 subjects have missings in `item_1`. Corrected in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another `dplyr` version is to first `group_by` `subject` and find out the group which has `any` `NA` value, then `group_by` column and calculate total value of `NA`s for `n` and divide it by total unique values of `subject` to get `prop`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

db %>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  summarise_all(~any(is.na(.))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-subject) %>%
  gather() %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(value), 
            prop = n/n_distinct(db$subject))

#   key       n  prop
#   <chr>  <int> <dbl>
#1 item_1     2   1  
#2 item_2     1   0.5
```

Comment: A nice solution. Just for people not using it regularly, `gather()` is from `tidyr` not `dplyr`.

Answer (score 1):

A different `tidyverse` possibility to assess the number of NA per item and per ID could be:

```
db %>%
 gather(var, val, -subject) %>%
 group_by(var, subject) %>%
 summarise(val = sum(is.na(val))) %>%
 spread(var, val)

  subject item_1 item_2
    <dbl>  <int>  <int>
1       1      1      2
2       2      1      0
```

Or if you want the overall number of NA and the proportion of NA per ID:

```
db %>%
 gather(var, val, -subject) %>%
 group_by(subject) %>%
 summarise(count = sum(is.na(val)),
           proportion = sum(is.na(val))/n())

  subject count proportion
    <dbl> <int>      <dbl>
1       1     3        0.5
2       2     1        0.5
```

Or if you want the count and proportion of NA just per item:

```
bind_rows(db %>%
 select(-subject) %>%
 gather(var, val) %>%
 group_by(var) %>%
 summarise(val = sum(is.na(val))) %>%
 spread(var, val) %>%
 mutate(type = "count"),
 db %>%
 select(-subject) %>%
 gather(var, val) %>%
 group_by(var) %>%
 summarise(val = sum(is.na(val))/n()) %>%
 spread(var, val) %>%
 mutate(type = "proportion"))

  item_1 item_2 type      
   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>     
1    2      2   count     
2    0.5    0.5 proportion
```

Or if you want the number and proportion of unique subjects with NA per item:

```
bind_rows(db %>%
 gather(var, val, -subject) %>%
 filter(is.na(val)) %>%
 group_by(var) %>%
 summarise(val = n_distinct(subject)) %>%
 spread(var, val) %>%
 mutate(type = "count"),
 db %>%
 gather(var, val, -subject) %>%
 group_by(var) %>%
 mutate(n = n_distinct(subject)) %>%
 filter(is.na(val)) %>%
 group_by(var) %>%
 summarise(val = first(n_distinct(subject)/n)) %>%
 spread(var, val) %>%
 mutate(type = "proportion"))

  item_1 item_2 type      
   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>     
1      2    1   count     
2      1    0.5 proportion
```

Comment: Please see the edits in my question. I hope it is clearer now.