# percentage of missing data in multiple variables in R

Tags: r, data-mining, percentage, missing-data

I have a data set which has **missing data**. I have found that there are **6 variables** with missing data. I wanted to check the **percentage of data** however I have used the **mean is.na** however I am not sure if this is correct and I know there is a much simpler way to check this than use repetitive codes as you can see below:

Question is, what is the best code to get percentage of **missing data in multiple variables**?

PS. I am hoping for it to look like the delete column code I have which removes the columns

--------------------**CODE**--------------------------------

```
mean(is.na(TrainDataSet$KF6 ))
mean(is.na(TrainDataSet$KF9 ))
mean(is.na(TrainDataSet$KF10 ))
mean(is.na(TrainDataSet$F1 ))
mean(is.na(TrainDataSet$T2 ))
mean(is.na(TrainDataSet$ST7 ))

#Delete columns with missing data from TrainingSet

TrainDataSet <- TrainDataSet[ , -c(11, 14 , 15 , 21 , 28, 54)]
```

I am getting responses for all the columns, please provide a solution for only the 6 columns above **(KF6, KF9, KF10, F1, T2, ST7) **

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33512837/6851825

Comment: Your solution shows all the columns. My question is to show only selected columns. I beleive, my coding is correct but I want to simplify it.

Comment: Try `colMeans(is.na(airquality[c("Solar.R", "Wind")]))` ie with your data `colMeans(is.na(TrainDataSet[c("KF6", "KF9", "KF10", "F1", "T2", "ST7")]))`

Comment: btw, it is recommended practice on this site to include sample data that others can use to try out and verify solutions. you can either 1) use a standard dataset like `airquality` (which has NAs), 2) use `dput()` with some representative subset of your data. This produces code that others can use to create an exact copy of your data object, 3) provide code to generate fake data, e.g. `TrainDataSet = data.frame(ok = 1:3, KF6 = c(1:2, NA), KF9 = c(NA, NA, "a"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
colMeans(is.na(airquality))

     Ozone    Solar.R       Wind       Temp      Month        Day 
0.24183007 0.04575163 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
```

If you just want certain columns, you could use:

```
colMeans(is.na(airquality[c("Solar.R", "Wind")]))
#colMeans(is.na(airquality[, 2:3]))   # equivalent by column position
   Solar.R       Wind 
0.04575163 0.00000000
```

Alternatively, with dplyr you could use `summarize(across...` to apply your code to every specified column:

```
library(dplyr)
airquality %>% summarize(across(c(Solar.R, Wind), ~mean(is.na(.x))))

     Solar.R Wind
1 0.04575163    0
```